# JAXB - Parse XML list sequentially (one by one)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have to parse XML which root element is a list:

```
<SomeObjectsCollection>
  <SomeObject><!-- content1 --></SomeObject>
  <SomeObject><!-- content2 --></SomeObject>
  <SomeObject><!-- content3 --></SomeObject>
    <!-- and hundreds more -->
</SomeObjectsCollection>
```

I don't want to parse whole XML to memory for performance reasons. I would rather write something like `Iterable<SomeObjetType>` that wouldn't enforce user to keep whole unmarshaled list in memory, just process it one by one.

So far I wrote such class which implements `Iterable<SomeObject>` and my own `Iterator` inside:

```java
public class SomeObjectsIterableParser implements Iterable<SomeObjectType> {

  private final Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller;
  private final XMLStreamReader xmlReader;

  public SomeObjectsIterableParser(Schema schema, java.io.Reader xmlStringReader) throws ExtractorException {
    try {
      jaxbUnmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeObjectType.class).createUnmarshaller();
      xmlReader = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(xmlStringReader);
    } catch (JAXBException | XMLStreamException e) {
      throw new ExtractorException("Could not create jaxbUnmarshaller", e);
    }
    jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema); //turns on schema validation

    //Move reader to first occurence of SomeObject - really necessary?
    try {
      while (xmlReader.hasNext()) {
        if (!xmlReader.isStartElement() || !xmlReader.getLocalName().equals("SomeObject"))
          xmlReader.next();
        else break;
      }
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<SomeObjectType> iterator() {
    return new MyIterator();
  }

  class MyIterator implements Iterator<SomeObjectType> {

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      try {
        return xmlReader.hasNext();
      } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public SomeObjectType next() {
      try {
        return (SomeObjectType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader);
      } catch (JAXBException | XMLStreamException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet");
    }
  }
}
```

I receive exception in `next()` method with message: `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 17; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'SomeObject'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We'd need everything for a full diagnostic, but most likely your schema declares <SomeObject> only as a child of <SomeObjectsCollection> and not as an acceptable standalone element in this schema. Since your Unmarshaller doesn't see what your XMLReader has read so far, it cannot know that <SomeObject> actually is a child of <SomeObjectsCollection>. You'd need to either declare your schema differently to declare such element independantly, or validate in another way (I know of none)

Comment: @kumesana You are right, this was the issue (but not the only one). I created connected question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733478/jaxb-schema-validation-when-unmarshalling-non-root-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [the article](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html) that describes what I want to do. As a result I wrote such code:

```
public class SomeObjectsIterableParser implements Iterable<SomeObjectType> {

  private final Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller;
  private final XMLStreamReader xmlReader;

  public SomeObjectsIterableParser(Schema schema, Reader SomeObjectResponse) throws ExtractorException {
    try {
      jaxbUnmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeObjectType.class).createUnmarshaller();
      xmlReader = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(SomeObjectResponse);
    } catch (JAXBException | XMLStreamException e) {
      throw new ExtractorException("Could not create jaxbUnmarshaller", e);
    }
    //jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema); //schema can handle only root element
    advanceReaderToFirstProfile();
  }

  private void advanceReaderToFirstProfile() {
    try {
      xmlReader.nextTag();
      while(!xmlReader.getLocalName().equals("SomeObject")) {
        xmlReader.nextTag();
      }
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<SomeObjectType> iterator() {
    return new MyIterator();
  }

  class MyIterator implements Iterator<SomeObjectType> {

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
      try {
        if (xmlReader.isWhiteSpace() && xmlReader.hasNext()) {
          //ommit witespaces
          xmlReader.nextTag();
        }
      } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      return xmlReader.isStartElement() 
          && xmlReader.getLocalName().equals("SomeObject");
    }

    @Override
    public SomeObjectType next() {
      try {
        JAXBElement<SomeObjectType> element = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader, SomeObjectType.class);
        return element.getValue();
      } catch (JAXBException | XMLStreamException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet");
    }
  }
}
```

**Be aware of 3 thinks:**

1. Schema validation can not be applied to non-root element. There is related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733478/jaxb-schema-validation-when-unmarshalling-non-root-element).
2. Use syntax:
   `JAXBElement<SomeObjectType> element = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader, SomeObjectType.class);`
   instead of
   `(SomeObjectType) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader);`.
   Otherwise you receive an exception:

   > java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
   >
   > - with linked exception:
   >     [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 22; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"SomeObject"). Expected elements are (none)]
3. Handle exceptions more carefully than in the example. `Iterable` and `Iterator` interfaces does not allow you to throw non-runtime exceptions.