# JAXB Schema validation when unmarshalling non-root element

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

When you unmarshal whole XML with JAXB, you can set XML schema to enable validation during parsing:

```
//javax.xml.validation.Schema schema = ...
jaxbUnmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(SomeRootType.class).createUnmarshaller();
jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
```

On the other hand, when you unmarshal list of `NestedObjest`s from XML, one by one (eg. to decrease memory usage) this method fails (as Schema only accepts root) with an exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 22; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'NestedObject'
```

It fails even if `NestedObjectType` is well-defined in the XSD. Is there any option to enable nested-object validation? Please note that defining new schema is a miserable option as the XSD is external for my application maintained by someone else.

Comment: could you provide some sample input, where this error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass to `unmarshal` method the class of the bound bean ? Like explained in [Example 65. Unmarshalling into a known type](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#unmarshalling-xmlrootelement-and-unmarshalling)

Comment: Can you modify the source xml ? eg: add xsi:type attribute

Comment: I can not modify xml/schema. In the example you linked teher is no validation enabled.

Comment: in which form do you have the xml ? sax, dom, stream ? The only way I managed to un-marshall without an element declaration in schema is using xsi:type in the xml.